# R - Trying to vectorize colnames selection from a data table

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize my code to make it more reproducible !

I would like to print a warning message in my R Markdown report when one of these columns is less than 5 ! Here is my first code before vectorization :

```
JO_ratio_JOUR <- JO_ratio_tranches[dir == "ALLER" & (.1_JO[4h_7h[_txcouv < 5 | .2_JO[7h_9h[_txcouv < 5 | .3_JO[9h_12h[_txcouv < 5 | .4_JO[12h_15h30[_txcouv < 5 | .5_JO[15h30_18h[_txcouv < 5 | 6_JO[18h_20h[_txcouv < 5 | .7_JO[20h_22h[_txcouv < 5 | .8_JO[22h_4h[_txcouv < 5), grep("txcouv", names(JO_ratio_tranches))]
if(!is_empty(JO_ratio_JOUR)){print(" WARNING: Ratio < 5% !")}

[1] "WARNING: Ratio(s) < 5% !"
```

OK !

But when I try to vectorize this code by a for loop, R prints the warning message everytime that he finds a value less than 5% in the table! :(

```
JO_ratio_JOUR <- JO_ratio_tranches[dir == "ALLER", ]
for(i in grep("txcouv", names(JO_ratio_JOUR))){
  if(JO_ratio_JOUR[[i]] < 5){print(" WARNING: Ratio < 5% !")}

[1] "WARNING: Ratio(s) < 5% !"
[1] "WARNING: Ratio(s) < 5% !"
[1] "WARNING: Ratio(s) < 5% !"
[1] "WARNING: Ratio(s) < 5% !"
```

KO !!!!

How can I just print ONE warning message if any of these columns are less than 5 ?

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Actually vectorization would be the non-loop version.

Comment: If you wanted to check whether any values in a vector are less than a certain number, you can use `any`, like this: `any(mtcars$disp < 100)` which will return a single TRUE/FALSE value.

Comment: @ Parfait: So how can I automate my colnames selection and verify that condition without selecting each column one by one, please ? Thanks again !

Comment: If you wanted to summarize every column, you could simply do `library(tidyverse); mtcars %>% summarize_all(.funs = function(x) any(x < 5))`

Comment: @Mako212: Thank you very much for your answer ! 

Comment: And a final example: `mtcars %>% summarize_all(.funs = function(x) any(x < 5)) %>% t() %>% all()` using transpose and `all()` to check if any value meets your condition. That single TRUE/FALSE can be used to return your error message.

Comment: Re-writing my earlier comment because I had a typo that would have thrown an error: more generically, if you store the column names you want to summarize in summaryCols, you can use `summarize_at(.vars = summaryCols, .funs = function(x) any(x < 5))` to avoid summarizing all the columns.

Comment: Thanks again but I have a little question... What should I write instead of summaryCols ? grep("txcouv",  names(my table)) ?

Comment: I believe that would work, `.vars` can take column names or indices as inputs.

Comment: Hi Mako212, sorry for the late reply ! I've tried your code : summarize_at(JO_ratio_tranches, .vars = grep("txcouv", names(JO_ratio_tranches)), .funs = function(x) any(x < 5)). It works very well. It notices by TRUE each column where the ratio is below 5 !

Comment: And here is the data.table way : `JO_ratio_JOUR <- JO_ratio_tranches[dir == "ALLER", .SD < 5, .SDcols = grep("txcouv", names(JO_ratio_tranches))]`